# equivalent python requests call to CURL request to upload image

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

I'm using Python requests module, but whatever I've tried to upload image, it succeeds, but image has errors when opening/reading.
I encode the image as base64, set content-type headers (image/png, image/jpeg etc...) etc...

Anyhow, I do the following using CURL and it works:

```
curl -u test@test.ca:test -H 'Content-Type: image/jpeg' --data-binary @test.jpeg -X POST 'https://test.test.com/api/upload.json?filename=test.jpeg'
```

What would be the equivalent of this request with the requests module in python (headers etc...)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To reproduce your `curl` command, you don't need to encode the image in base64: `--data-binary @test.jpeg` curl option sends `test.jpeg` file as is:

```
import requests

r = requests.post('https://example.com/api/upload.json?filename=test.jpeg', 
                  data=open('test.jpeg', 'rb'), 
                  headers={'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg'},
                  auth=('test@test.ca', 'test')) # username, password
```

Comment: this WORKED, because I changed instead of using files={'file.png':etc...} to data=etc.. instead. thank you.

Comment: ...and i was just about to switch over to urrlib2, which i have a working implementation for.

Answer (score 1):

```
headers = {'Content-Type' : 'image/jpeg'}
params = {'filename' : 'test.jpg'}
r = requests.post("https://test.test.com/api/upload.json",
                   auth=('user','pw'), headers=headers, params=params)
```

Comment: files ={'test.png':base64.b64encode(open('test.png', 'r').read())}

Comment: I've already been doing that type of request. thanks for the response though. I need to include it with the files. and it will work, but fail to open/read the image after it's been uploaded. but works with CURL